# Value is not incrementing accurately inside coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, timedelta

I am new to C# and Unity. I am trying to increment a value (Counter) by 1 every 5 seconds. However, the value increases by 4 every 5 seconds. The counter should also stop when the value reaches 5. However, it continues to increase til I manually stop it.

```
public float energyLevel = 0;

public IEnumerator DoIncrement()
 {
     while (true)
     {
         while ((Math.Abs(Counter - 5) > Mathf.Epsilon)) 
         {
         float duration = 5f; 
         float nTime = 0;
             while (nTime <= 1f)
             {
                 nTime += Time.deltaTime / duration;
                 yield return null;
             }
         Counter++;
         Debug.Log("Counter = " + Counter);
         }
     StopCoroutine(DoIncrement());
     yield return null;
     break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `Counter` is undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a method where you create an object of WaitForSecondsRealtime and pass any number of seconds you want to hold the iteration.

Ex.

```
public IEnumerator DoIncrement(){
 int counter = 0;
 while (true)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(5f);
     counter += 1; 
 }
}
```

`yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(X);`

The above statement will stop your coroutine from executing for X numbers of seconds.

and **counter += 1**  and **counter++** will add 1 eachtime when it get executed.

Comment: Thanks. I've replaced my code with this and replaced `while(true)` with `while (Counter != 5)`. However, the counter increases from 0 to 6 (in 1 second), waits 2 seconds, then increases from 7 to 11 (in 1 second) and continues to do this.

Comment: @NorthernStars did you replace your code with what's in the answer here?  Or are you still calling `DoIncrement()` inside of itself? You should consider not doing that

Comment: Can you share the code again so that we can understand what is causing the problem? Please don't stop a coroutine within itself instead use ```yield break;``` to stop coroutine or use ```break;``` to stop ```while()```

Answer (score 2):

Replace these lines:

```
 StopCoroutine(DoIncrement());
 yield return null;
 break;
```

with a simple break; or yield break; Both will work.

Your problem is that "StopCoroutine(DoIncrement())" will make a new call to DoIncrement recursively, and you'll never stop. StopCoroutine() cannot be used in this way for iterators (and there is absolutely no need to stop it from within).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've made this change. The Counter value now increases by 5 every 5 seconds. Also, it doesn't stop when the Counter value reaches 5 (it continues to increase).

Comment: What datatype is counter? int? float?

Comment: Counter datatype is Float

Comment: You should never ever try to compare a floating point value with == !

Comment: Changed to `(Math.Abs(Counter - 5) > Mathf.Epsilon)` Issue still persists.

Comment: Why not simply change "Counter" to an int? And also DEBUG the code with a break-point?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you are starting multiple instances of DoIncrement. Debug the code!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't have to Stop a coroutine within itself. It is automatically stopped when it reach the end of the code.

Here is a simple working exemple that you can use :

```
    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine(IncrementCoroutine(5, 1));
    }

    private IEnumerator IncrementCoroutine(int maxCounter, float timeBetweenIncrement)
    {
        WaitForEndOfFrame endofFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        int counter = 0;
        float timer = 0;

        while (counter < maxCounter)
        {
            print($"Counter : {counter}");
            while (timer < timeBetweenIncrement)
            {
                timer += Time.deltaTime;
                yield return endofFrame;
            }

            timer = 0;
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no sense in wrapping it in a while loop like that if you break at the end of it and there's no `continue` used anywhere.

You don't need to use `StopCoroutine` from inside a coroutine to stop it - just allow the method to return.

You have no guarantees that Counter will ever get close to the value of 5 so your while loop may never terminate. Better to loop while Counter is below some amount.

And I would recommend using something like `WaitForSeconds` to handle the time counting instead of doing it yourself:

```
private int Counter = 0; // define Counter
public float energyLevel = 0;

public IEnumerator DoIncrement()
 {
     WaitForSeconds waiter = new WaitForSeconds(5f);
     while (Counter < 5) 
     {
         yield return waiter;
         Counter++;
         Debug.Log("Counter = " + Counter);
     }
 }
```

Also, the question does not contain enough information to reproduce your problem of the counter increasing multiple times within one period of 5 seconds. That part can not be answered adequately. It may be caused by you starting the coroutine 4 times at once.